# more tough or tougher

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives, adverbs

I would like to say the following:

> Personally, farewell is farewell not matter you say goodbye to small or huge group of people. The more you were attached to them the more tough it will be.

my question is, is it correct to say "..the more tough" or it should be "tougher"

Also if you have any suggestion regarding changing the sentence please do not hesitate.

Comment: I don't think you mean to say "not" in the fifth word of your example; and you need a word such as _whether_ between "matter" and "you" (or instead of "not matter"). But this whole question smacks of being a proofreading request, in my opinion.

Comment: @SvenYargs, I think you and he mean **no matter** plus a following word, because he already wrote **not**.

Comment: @Helmar: Yes, my first hint was meant to suggest replacing "not" with "no." Then I saw the missing "whether" and tried to point out that problem, too. But Elpharaoh has two choices at that point: "farewell is farewell no matter whether you say goodbye..." or "farewell is farewell whether you say goodbye..." The second is a bit less long-winded, I think, but both are used in conversational English. (Note that "to small or huge group of people" has yet another syntactical problem, to say nothing of the odd placement of "attached" in the second sentence. But that's proofreading, isn't it?)

Comment: @SvenYargs oh, I only now realized you wrote _don't think_; my mistake.You are completely right, also regarding the other problems. That's why I stuck to the core question in my answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three degrees of comparison:

The positive: tough

The comparative (between two things): tougher

The superlative (among three or more things): toughest

You are expressing the comparative between:

The more you were attached to them | the more tough it will be

Avoid *double comparisons*, which is formed by incorrectly by both the addition of *--er* or *--est* and the use of *more* or *most*.

The boss is tough.

His superior is tougher. [NOT: superior is more tougher]

> The more you were attached to them | the tougher it will be

CORRECTED:

Personally, I believe/think farewell is farewell, whether it's to a small group of people or a large one. The more that you allow yourself to become attached, the tougher it will be for you to leave them.

If anybody else can improve upon this, by all means...

Answer (score 1):

Citing the rule of thumb for comparatives with -er versus those using more:

> [M]onosyllabic adjectives generally form their comparative form with -er in English, whereas polysyllabic adjectives prefer to use more. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparative#-er_vs._more))

Specifically to tough you can use a dictionary.

> **tough**  *(tŭf) adj.* **tough·er, tough·est** ([American Heritage Dictionary](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=tough))

Answer (score 0):

The comparative form of "tough" is "tougher". Although I cannot find a formal reference for this, a quick search for "comparative form of tough" will show you this is true. Similarly, the superlative form is "toughest". The following sources are not sources I would ordinarily cite, but for this purpose I think they will suffice.

[Longman English Dictionary](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/tough_1): *tough* : comparative tougher, superlative toughest

[Yourdictionary.com](http://www.yourdictionary.com/tough): *tough* : (comparative tougher, superlative toughest)